# Estimation update for finding complex roots using Müller's method

Tags: numerical-methods

Let there be a polynomial whose roots to be found and let us start with initial guesses $x_0\ x_1\ x_2$.
Let the quadratic  $a(x-x_2)^2+b(x-x_2)+c$  developed from these values have complex roots. Denote them as $\alpha+\beta i $   and $\alpha-\beta i$.   One of them is to be chosen as $x_3$, the first estimate.
Which root should I proceed with? It is said that one should choose the largest denominator from $x_2+\frac{-2c}{b\pm \sqrt {b^2-4ac}} $ to determine $x_3$ but mathematically I cannot compare two complex numbers and choose one over the other.

Comment: You compare the *magnitude* of the denominators to determine which is largest. And if you get equal magnitudes then it usually does not matter which is taken.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt If $b^2-4ac<0$ I get a complex number there. Are you referring to the modulus of it?

Comment: Yes, you compare the moduli of both denominators, even in the real case.